Do some covariant derivative identities depend on convention?
I'm studying from the Semi-Riemannian Geometry by Newman. In it, let $\nabla_X:\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\mathfrak{X}(M)$ be derived from a connection $\nabla:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times\mathfrak{X}(M)\to\mathfrak{X}(M)$. And let $\nabla_X$ be the tensor derivation corresponding to it, i.e. $\nabla_X:\mathcal{T}^r_s\to\mathcal{T}^r_s$. Then the total covariant derivative is the family of linear maps $\nabla:\mathcal{T}^r_s\to\mathcal{T}^r_{s+1}$ such that
$$(\nabla T)(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^r,X,Y_1,\ldots,Y_s)=(\nabla_XT)(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^r,Y_1,\ldots,Y_s)\tag{1}$$
There is an identity/result that says
$$\nabla_X(T\otimes S)=\nabla_XT\otimes S+T\otimes\nabla_XS\tag{2}$$
I'm trying to get to a tensor product identity for the total covariant derivative from the above. First I'm trying a special case in which $T=Y$ is a vector field and $S=\omega$ is a covector field. Since the above identity holds, I can act both sides on $(\eta,Z)$ where $\eta,Z$ are arbitrary dual vector and vector fields respectively. Acting LHS on these arguments,
$$\nabla_X(Y\otimes\omega)(\eta,Z)=\nabla(Y\otimes\omega)(\eta,X,Z)\tag{3}$$
Acting RHS first term on the arguments,
$$(\nabla_XY\otimes \omega)(\eta,Z)=\nabla_XY(\eta)\omega(Z)=\nabla Y(\eta,X)\omega(Z)=(\nabla Y\otimes\omega)(\eta,X,Z)\tag{4}$$
And similarly for second RHS term,
$$(Y\otimes\nabla_X\omega)(\eta,Z)=(Y\otimes\nabla\omega)(\eta,X,Z)\tag{5}$$
Finally we get
$$\nabla(Y\otimes\omega)(\eta,X,Z)=(\nabla Y\otimes\omega)(\eta,X,Z)+(Y\otimes\nabla\omega)(\eta,X,Z)\tag{6}$$
Since the arguments for all terms are exactly the same with the same order, we can conclude $$\nabla(Y\otimes\omega)=(\nabla Y\otimes\omega)+(Y\otimes\nabla\omega)\tag{7}$$

But the book also mentions that some texts follow this convention:
$$(\nabla T)(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^r,Y_1,\ldots,Y_s,X)=(\nabla_XT)(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^r,Y_1,\ldots,Y_s)\tag{8}$$
If I repeat the exact same exercise as above, acting all terms on $(\eta,Z)$, I get
$$\nabla(Y\otimes\omega)(\eta,Z,X)=(\nabla Y\otimes\omega)(\eta,X,Z)+(Y\otimes\nabla\omega)(\eta,Z,X)\tag{9}$$
Now the order of the arguments is different and I can't really conclude identity (7). So my question is, am I missing something and identity (7) still holds even with the second convention? Or does it actually depend on what convention we've chosen for arguments ordering in total covariant derivative's definition?

Think of $\nabla_X$ as a directional derivative. You have to decide where to put the direction $X$. I prefer to make it the first argument. Also, instead of listing the arguments separated by commas, I use the tensor product. Therefore, for me $$\langle\nabla(Y\otimes\omega),X\otimes\eta\otimes Z\rangle = \langle \nabla Y,X\otimes\eta\rangle\langle\omega,Z\rangle + \langle Y,\eta\rangle\langle\nabla\omega,X\otimes Z\rangle. $$

I'm pretty sure (7) isn't true in general. Without evaluating $\nabla$ w.r.t. a vector field, it's the exterior covariant derivative, which isn't Leibniz over the tensor product in general.
To make things clearer, I'm going to work with a connection $\nabla:\Gamma E\to \Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$ on a smooth vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$. The derivation $\nabla_X:\Gamma E\to \Gamma E$ is Leibniz over the tensor product (7). In your case, it's clear that both $\nabla(Y\otimes \omega)$ and $Y\otimes\nabla\omega$ are in the space $\Gamma(E\otimes E^*\otimes T^*M)$, but $\nabla Y \otimes \omega$ is in $\Gamma(E\otimes T^*M \otimes E^*)$. There is a canonical isomorphism relating the latter space to the former. When you go to just work with tangent bundles i.e. $E=TM$, these all appear to live in the same space.
